# Validate and append phone input Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, append

I have some input field that always has to have + first in input

**HTML**

```
<input id="phone">
```

**JS**

```
  $("#phone").keydown(function (e) {
      $(this).get(0).value+="+";
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

The problem is you can see in this fiddle
http://fiddle.jshell.net/nqkeuspf/

UPDATE

```
$("#phone").keydown(function (e) {
          var firstChar = $(this).val().substr(0, 1);
        // Check first character.
        if (firstChar != '+'){       
          $(this).val('+' + $(this).val())
        }   
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190,107]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

The problem is that it doesn not check +

Fiddle
http://fiddle.jshell.net/bjsrk83j/3/

Comment: why are you appending plus signs?

Comment: You are adding a `+` on every keydown. What are you expecting and why are you doing that? Your problem statement is severely lacking in detail

Comment: This is just my example, i know i didnt make it right:(

Comment: I always have to have + as first sign

Comment: why don't you just add it if user doesn't before posting to server?

Comment: Yes but what if user enters +

Comment: you check for it. trim the value and test first character

Comment: Also `+` is only necessary for foreign codes. Consider this phone number: `0612345678`. It's a Dutch standard (made up) mobile number. However with country code this is `0031 612345678`, with plus this becomes `+31 612345678`. So when I enter a standard phone number a leading `+` isn't desired.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as `keypress` handler. It allows only numbers and you can supply it with a `filter` to allow other characters like +. Esc allows the user to cancel.

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function handleInputKey(filter, e) // append filter as string '+-.,' for example.
{
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }

    //allow only numeric input
    //48-57 and 96-105 (keyboard left and numpad)
    //also delete, back space, esc, enter, arrows and tab
    if ((filter && filter.match(escapeRegExp(String.fromCharCode(e.which)))) || ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) && (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

    }


}

//the onkeydown handler   

function handleInputKeyFinish(e) {
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        this.blur();
    }


}

function stripAndAppendPlus(e) {
    //when the users pastes a value delete invalid characters.
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    e.target.value = "+" + e.target.value;
}


$("#phone").keydown(handleInputKeyFinish);
$("#phone").keypress(handleInputKey.bind($("#phone")[0], null));
$("#phone").blur(stripAndAppendPlus);
```

Solution in Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/bqa87bwh/1/

Even simpler not using jQuery or JavaScript. This is [HTML5](http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms) so not compatible with older browsers.

```
<input type="phone" pattern="^\+?\d{7,13}$" required />
```

`pattern` checks the input against a reg ex. This reg ex allows phone numbers consisting out of 7 to 13 numbers and they can begin with a `+`.

`required` --> this field has to contain a value otherwise the form won't be submitted.

Solution in Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/e76t41rj/1/

Comment: Please use keypress, my code doesn't need exceptions for ctrl-a tab etc.

Comment: @MichaelDancevic Fiddles added, have fun

Comment: Then not use it, use the other sample I provided.

Comment: @MichaelDancevic Use the other sample. It suits all your needs. It allows only numeric input and keeps the controls keys working. On blur it trims not numeric characters (coming from paste event e.g.) and adds a leading `+` to the phone number. Enjoy. Please provide more explanation to your answers on comments. I don't want HTML5 or I need a plus sign sounds a little unthankful.